# Android: getString causes NPE in Application subclass

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, robolectric, android-context, getstring

I'm experiencing a weird bug in my application. I have a `MyApplication` class extending `Application`. In its `onCreate()` method I initialize some 3rd party libs which require API keys stored in a string resource file. Basically, it works fine on devices that I can test with: Nexus S and Galaxy SIII. But I got a couple entries from crash reporting system and if I run Robolectric test for `MyApplication.onCreate()` I'm getting NullPointerException from `getString()` method.

I wonder if somebody had same issue and what might be the cause?

Log output for test (crash report also refers to the same line in `setupAnalyticsCrashReportingAndThirdPartySdks`):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getResName(ShadowResources.java:100)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getString(ShadowResources.java:130)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContext.getString(ShadowContext.java:54)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java)
at com.myapp.android.MyApplication.setupAnalyticsCrashReportingAndThirdPartySdks(MyApplication.java:113)
at com.myapp.android.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:42)
at com.myapp.android.util.UtilitiesTest.setUp(UtilitiesTest.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:106)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
```

Update: A little piece of the code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
```

{

```
private static MyApplication _instance;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    setupAnalyticsCrashReportingAndThirdPartySdks();
}

public MyApplication()
{
    _instance = this;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance()
{
    return _instance;
}

private void setupAnalyticsCrashReportingAndThirdPartySdks()
{
    String env = getString(R.string.environment); // Crash here
    if (env != null && env.equalsIgnoreCase("dev"))
    {
        FlurryAnalytics.setDebugMode(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd recommend adding a bit of your code to the question so we can get a bit more context.

Comment: Does reading the source for that library help?  Not sure this is the right code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/robolectric/2.0-alpha-2/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowResources.java#ShadowResources.getResName%28int%29

Comment: @DigCamara see update for code. In my opinion it should work properly, but something strange is happening there.

Comment: Can you post your strings.xml as well? (it should be in src\res\values). If you haven't defined environment in there, it should (I'm guessing here) be part of the library's resources.

Comment: @DigCamara the file is called res/values/settings.xml, but it shouldn't be a problem, since it's basically just another string resource file. And this value is being read properly from Activity context in another place of the app. I'll try to create a separate project with Robolectric and test different options for string resources, may be I can find out something that way.